# Where/How to buy One piece Chapter 1000 manga hardcopy in USA?

Tags: one-piece, manga-production, shonen-jump

Does anyone know where to buy the original hardcopy of One Piece chapter 1000 in USA? I'm looking to order it online, would be happy to buy and get it shipped from Japan too.

Comment: Since *One Piece* is serialized in *Shonen Jump* magazine, did you mean how to buy the Japanese magazine or the tankobon that includes it? Individual chapters are not known to be sold separately.

Comment: Yes, then the magazine.

Comment: For starter, chapter 1000 was serialized in [Weekly Shonen Jump Issue 5-6, 2021](https://jump.fandom.com/wiki/Weekly_Shonen_Jump_Issue_5-6,_2021) (Japanese: [週刊少年ジャンプ 2021年5・6合併号](https://shonenjumpplus.com/magazine/13933686331776635931), digital version). However, as someone who isn't living in the USA and not accustomed to buying the hardcopy version, I can't really suggest anything for now.